# Getting a cookie of another Tab with javascript

Tags: javascript, tabs, session-cookies

Is it possible to get cookies of one Tab with javascript code running in another Tab?
(different domains)
Or with any other languages other than javascript?

Comment: Emphatically "NO". That would be a fatal security flaw in any browser that allowed it.

Comment: have a look here -> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

Comment: Ahh Thought so but needed to be sure, for security reasons. Thanks. If any of you post it as an answer I'll mark it answered.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As I gathered from the comments, there is no possible way as it would be a security issue.